# Jest snapshot with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

i'm trying to do a snapshot of this component :

```
export default class LoginExternalApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let store = this.props.store.getState();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {store.facebookToken ? null : <FacebookButtonConnect />}
        {store.spotifyToken ? null : <SpotifyButtonConnect />}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've got a `store` variable inside the `render()` method, which call a props.

Here is my test file based on Jest librairie :

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import LoginExternalApi from '../app/scenes/LoginExternalApi';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('LoginExternalApi scene renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <LoginExternalApi />
  ).toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

And here is my error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined`

Any idea of how my test should be written ? Should I mock my store & how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how your store normally ends up there as a prop and how you want to test that your component renders correctly.

For example, you could mock your store and then snapshot one version for each of your providers.

```
test('LoginExternalApi scene renders Spotify connect button', () =>
  let store = {
    getState() {
      return { spotifyToken: 'foo' }
    }
  };

  const tree = renderer.create(
    <LoginExternalApi store={store} />
  ).toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

However, it looks like you're using Redux and you might find that as your components grow they need to work with other parts of the store API —
 dispatching actions, for example. At this point, it may well be easier to test against a real store, rather than mocking it.

The [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) API makes it trivial to source your store for a given component, rather than having to think about passing the store as a prop at every level.

```
const tree = renderer.create(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <LoginExternalApi />
  </Provider>
).toJSON();
```

So long as your `<LoginExternalApi />` component interfaces with the store through the [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function, then you can wrap it in an explicit store for testing.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you Dan.